# How to upload a file from WP directory automatically?

Tags: uploads, import, ftp

I would like to upload a CSV file from local ftp to WP directory and import this CSV file from WP directory to mysql database automatically? It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of plugins used for this like CSV Import for WordPress
and WP CSV to Database - Insert CSV file content into WordPress database